# How to enable Kerberos for Apache Spark 2.0 and 2.1?

Tags: apache-spark

I need to enable Kerberos for Apache Spark 2.0 and 2.1. I have Googled but there is no document about how to enable Kerberos for Apache Spark v2.x.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using Spark as a _client_ of a Kerberized Hadoop cluster, or Spark as a _service_ that you want to protect with Kerberos authentication?

Comment: So I need to configure Kerberos enabled for Apache Spark to let someone using it to test it. So I guess both?

Comment: AFAIK Spark services are **not** kerberizable...

Comment: But if your users just need to run Spark jobs *(using a Linux shell or a Jupyter notebook)* against a kerberized Hadoop cluster, then Spark will use the available Kerberos ticket in the user session, automatically. It's for long-running Streaming jobs, or scheduled executions, that it becomes more tricky...

Answer (score 0):

Could you please share what you have tried till now or share the error you are facing. It will help us to answer better.

If you are using any distribution , below links will help.

[Cloudera](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-5-x/topics/sg_spark_auth.html)

[Horton](https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.3.6/bk_spark-guide/content/installing-kerb-spark.html)

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet, I just tried to google some document about how to enable Kerberos for Apache Spark, but I didn't find anything. If you have some steps how to enable it, please share it. I will try it. Thanks.